# newtonsoft json serialize without property name

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2013, json.net

I have classes shared between clients and servers. In theory, if properties are serialized and de-serialized in the same order, I do not even need property names in JSON string and serializing and deserializing even much faster and json strings seem to be much smaller.
I can do it with my own code but how can I do the same using Newtonsoft JSON.Net?
I am using C# VS2015, JSON.Net 9.0.

Comment: Why is so critical for you the performance of json (de)serialization? It sounds to me like you will spend a lot of time and you will gain very little. Interesting read: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: If you're worried about compact size and high speed transfer of data over the wire, you might want to check out [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) instead of trying to mangle JSON.